# How to get result information when updating mysql table with Doctrine ORM in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am developing with symfony 1.4 and using Doctrine ORM.
After building schema and models i've got some classes for work with database. I can also use Doctrine_query .... The only thing, that i cann`t understend is:

I need to update table.

```
Doctrine_Query::create()->update('table')->.....->execute().
```

or

```
$tbl = new Table();
$tbl->assignIdentifier($id);
if($tbl->load()){
    $tbl->setFieldname('value');
    $tbl->save();
}
```

how can i understend was it successful result of query or not ? and how much rows was updated.

p.s. the same question is for delete operation.

Comment: Most functions like `save()`, `delete` and so on of most ORM-s will return `true` on success and `false` on failure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything is in the doc for [update](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries) and [delete](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#delete-queries).

> When executing DQL UPDATE and DELETE queries the executing of a query returns the number of affected rows.

See examples:

```php
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('Account')
        ->set('amount', 'amount + 200')
        ->where('id > 200');

$rows = $q->execute();

echo $rows;
```

```php
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->delete('Account a')
        ->where('a.id > 3');

$rows = $q->execute();

echo $rows;
```

This is related to DQL (when you are using doctrine queries). But I think `->save()` will return the current object or true/false as @PLB commented.

Answer (score 7):

```
$statement = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();

// the counter of rows which are updated
$counter = $statement->rowCount();
```

It works for me very well with doctrine 2 in symfony 2 project

Answer (score 0):

```
$nrRows = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeUpdate('UPDATE ...');
```

The documentation for [executeUpdate](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#executeupdate):

```
  /**
     * Executes an SQL INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query with the given parameters
     * and returns the number of affected rows.
     *
     * This method supports PDO binding types as well as DBAL mapping types.
     *
     * @param string         $query  The SQL query.
     * @param mixed[]        $params The query parameters.
     * @param int[]|string[] $types  The parameter types.
     *
     * @return int The number of affected rows.
     *
     * @throws DBALException
     */
    public function executeUpdate($query, array $params = [], array $types = [])
```